# What does |= mean in c++

Tags: c++

I have code line

```
int i =0;
result |= EXPECT_EQUAL(list.size(),     3);
```

What does `|=` mens?

I was trying to compile something like:

```
int result |= 5;
```

but got error:

```
aaa.cpp:26:16: error: expected initializer before ‘|=’ token
```

Comment: google it.  plus elmost every language has this operator, not only C++

Comment: It's equivalent to `result = result | EXPECT_EQUAL(list.size(),     3);` `int result |= 5;` doesn't operate on an initialised value as the error message states.

Comment: Not related to your question, I noticed that you've asked **395** questions but have only casted **37** upvotes. Are all those answers not helpful to you?

Comment: @DavidHaim just saying , its kinda hard to google these symbols

Comment: google "list of operators C++"

Comment: @MohitBhasi Do you know `+=`, `*=`, `-=`, `/=`... etc? It is the same thing, but with operator `|` which is bitwise OR.

Comment: You can't use compound assignment operators during initialization.

Comment: I'm not too fond of all the downvotes. It is difficult to google for an operator that does not contain any English words. How is the OP even supposed to know that it's an *operator* in the first place?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Agreed. It is a poor question but IMHO does not deserves the -5

Comment: It deserves a -1 from me and I don't care how many it already has.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I noticed the OP has asked many questions about operators before and most of them were duplicates. Moreover he didn't learn anything over a few years

Answer (score 38):

`a |= b;` is just syntactic sugar for `a = a | b;`. Same syntax is valid for almost every operator in C++.

But `int i |= 5;` is an error, because in the definition line you must have an initialisation, that is an expression that does not use the variable being declared.

```
int i=3;
i |= 5;
```

is valid and will give value 7 (3 | 5) to `i`.

Comment: While `a |= b;` and `a = a | b;` produce the same result, [they are not strictly equal](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice) in terms of implementation.

Comment: The implementation may be different or may be the same at the choice of the compiler... anyway implementation and the various optimizations are not defined by the standard

Comment: @CoryKramer: That's nonsense; the accepted answer there is mired in history and low-level implementation specifics; the operations, per the _language_, are in fact entirely equivalent. At least it's correct in admitting that the two will compile to the same code.

Answer (score 11):

It's the operator for assignment by bitwise OR.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment

> ```
> int result |= 5;
> ```

You cannot initialize an `int` and assign something to it at the same time. Initialization and assignment are different things. You'd have to write:

```
int result = 0;
result |= 5;
```

If this is what you intend, of course. Since `int result |= 5;` is not C++, we can only guess about your intention.